# Remove DHL Shipping Method If Free Shipping is Available

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping, dhl

```
I have Magneto 2.2.4 in which I have to hide DHL Shipping Method if Free Shipping is Available.

My Free Shipping is available if minimum order amount is greater than 200 .

Is there any Admin option to do this or I have to create a Module or install an Extension.


My Condition Setting
```

[image]

```
My Action Setting
```

[image]

Comment: You can do this using plugin of magento.

Comment: Thanks For your Answer @Dhiren Vasoya
I have change little bit in my Question have you any idea about it.

Comment: You can do this by coding, I post answer check that one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no admin option to do that, you would need to create a module and hook into native DHL carrier one. But what you can try and do is to set cart price rule that does not require a coupon (so it will be applied automatically) and set it as follows:

In conditions tab

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal (Excl. Tax)  equals or greater than  200
```

In actions tab make discount amount 0 and under `Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items`:

```
 Free Shipping: For shipment with matching items
```

This should switch shipping price to 0 for all shipments. If you have many options in DHL carrier that may not be enough though.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Zefiryn 
I Have a question Like if Customer is from Canada and Purchased a product more than 200$ So I want to make shipping Free.
I have created cart rule for that but i think it doesn't apply on  my Cart Page. Have you any idea to do that.
I have attached screenshot of cart Rule.

Comment: Have you went to checkout and provided shipping address? Since you've added a rule that shipping country must be set to CA you need to go to firs step of the checkout and provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this things using custom code.

1. create plugin into your custom extension.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
        <plugin name="shipping_method_management" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Now you need to put your logic into the that plugin file.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model\ShippingMethodManagement.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model;

    class ShippingMethodManagement 
    {


     public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
     {
         return $this->filterOutput($output);
     }

     private function filterOutput($output)
     {

         $isfree = 0;
         foreach ($output as $shippingMethod) 
         {
              if ($shippingMethod->getCarrierCode() == 'freeshipping' && $shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping') 
              {
                  $isfree = 1;
              }
         }
         if ($isfree) 
         {
            // Freeshipping enable and available, so you can hide another method which you want and return that things.
         }
         return $output;
     }
  }
```